# How to make HTML printer friendly?

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm in the process of building a character generator for a role playing game, and I've run into the issue of my formatting not carrying over when I try to print it or convert it to pdf (as shown below). I'm looking for the generator to fit on a single page of letter paper (8.5in/11in). Is it a matter of reformatting the CSS I have to fit those dimensions, or is there a HTML or CSS solution that can amend this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Background colours are usually not printed, and everything else looks similar in your screenshots. The printed page is narrower, so some whitespace gets squeezed - you can get the same result on the screen by narrowing the window - but other than that, I don't see any problems. I suppose the real question is, what do you _want_ to happen on the printed page?

Comment: I want to know if I have to *manually* account for narrowed white space when formatting, or if there's a coding solution to take care of that for me.

Comment: Yes, there are solutions using CSS, but you still haven't said what needs to happen. For instance, take the first box of text. "Lancer RPG Generator". If the box is defined as, say, 30% wide, and the text always needs to fit in the box like in the first screenshot, then define a font size in vw. If all you want is some padding, than add padding. Etc. Basic responsiveness. You can also put specialised styles for printing in a media query.

Comment: Preferably I need the layout of the second image to match the first; ideally the dimensions of layout would be the same as a piece of paper, so everything still fits on one page. I'm using grid for the layout and placement of boxes, with flex to order things within boxes. I haven't really defined things in percentages or vw. If it's matter of manually tweaking padding and font size, then I'm fine with that.